# How do you add server side functionality to an already created react app?

Tags: reactjs

I've already built a create react app. I'm currently learning back-end development, and I was wondering how do I separated the scripts that are to run from the server from the scripts that run from the client? My app is currently deployed on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

React js is a UI toolkit and does not have the ability to do server-side processing. If you want to add back-end functionality to your react app, you can build it separately in form of a REST API. (You can use nodejs, python, java etc. whichever suits your application)

You have to make API calls from your react app to receive and send data from front-end to back-end and vice versa.